# IDA Pro: Is there a command-line way to generate idb files without generating asm files?

Tags: ida

Currently, I'm generating a bunch of `.idb` files in a batch via `idaw.exe -B <FILE>`. (I'm using IDA Pro 6.8.) This process also creates many `.asm` files - one for each `.idb` file created. I don't need these files, so they just get ignored/deleted.

Is there a way to generate `.idb` files from the command line without also generating the `.asm` files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the bottom of [the help page](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/417.shtml) you can see the following:

> For batch mode, IDA must be invoked with the following command line:
>
> ```
> ida -B input-file
> ```
>
> which is **equivalent to**:
>
> ```
> ida -c -A -Sanalysis.idc input-file
> ```

I.e. the actual analysis and writing of .asm is done by `analysis.idc`. Looking into it, we can see:

```
static main()
{
  // turn on coagulation of data in the final pass of analysis
  set_inf_attr(INF_AF, get_inf_attr(INF_AF) | AF_DODATA | AF_FINAL);
  // .. and plan the entire address space for the final pass
  auto_mark_range(0, BADADDR, AU_FINAL);

  msg("Waiting for the end of the auto analysis...\n");
  auto_wait();

  msg("\n\n------ Creating the output file.... --------\n");
  auto file = get_idb_path()[0:-4] + ".asm";

  auto fhandle = fopen(file, "w");
  gen_file(OFILE_ASM, fhandle, 0, BADADDR, 0); // create the assembler file
  msg("All done, exiting...\n");
  qexit(0); // exit to OS, error code 0 - success
}
```

So just make your own copy of the script, remove the part writing out `.asm` file (`gen_file` call), and run IDA with your own script:

`ida -c -A -Smyanalysis.idc -Lida.log input-file`

Comment: This was a while ago, but where are the `msg` prints directed? This script file still looks identical to what you have posted here. I don't see any of those prints when running the script as shown.

Comment: @sherrellbc set IDALOG=ida.log or use `-Lida.log` switch

Comment: If a Python script is used as the argument for `-S`, is `ida_auto.auto_wait()` a sufficient call to have a similar effect as `auto_wait` from the `analysis.idc` script?